# error in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i create a database in phpmyadmin, and it works well, but when i upload this php file and sql server in hosting, than i see the error: Unknown column 'Useremail' in 'field list';
but in localhost it works well.

here is code

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO users (First, Last, Username, Password, Useremail, Paypal, Country, City,        PostalCode, Adress)
VALUES('$first', '$last', '$username', '$password', '$useremail', '$paypal', '$country', '$city', '$postalcode', '$adress')";

if ($exist) {
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo "You are registered successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
} else {
    echo '<button onclick="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</button>';
}
```

Comment: Did you import the `.sql` on your server ?

Comment: Have you created that field in  your server database

Comment: check is it `Useremail` or `UserEmail` in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Post the SQL script. Check all the column names in the table are same as in the insert query.

Comment: check server database if created then check column names, may be problem in upper/lower case column names.

Comment: I think user12 may be onto something. Case sensitivity can be different for each database. This is a setting during database creation time. Your hosting DB may have a different setting to localhost.

Comment: problem about only useremail, paypal and postalcode columns, when i clear they, it work well, but when i add this tables in different names, there was the error,

Comment: @xrcwrn i made a db, and table with phpmyadmin, in localhost, and it worked, but when i export sql file and upload in host, this columns aren`t working,